# Swift Avfoundation: QRcode scanning error in bright ambient

Tags: swift, avfoundation, qr-code

I'm using the example from [here](http://www.appcoda.com/qr-code-reader-swift/) to built a qrcode scanning apps and it work perfectly fine for paper, or normal light

in normal condition, the qrcode is looks like below:
(the line are thicker and those dots are stick near to each other)
[image]

**My problem:** when the ambient is bright, and the phone is bright (especially from retina display like SamsungEdge 7), the qrcode scanned become like below. **Unable to read the qrcode anymore!**
(the line become thinner and the dots become smaller and further apart)
[image]

any suggestion or where/how i can fix this kind of error? because ZXING is enable to scan even in my 'error' scenario.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a zxing port to Objective-C which you may try https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC

Comment: @kennytm after testing, i think the problem is not at the scanning but is at the camera itself.... below is how i make the workaround.

Comment: @kennytm Thanks, I'm using swift. and now using Zbar (also in obj-c)... tutorial of bridging zbar in swift: https://gist.github.com/wszdwp/205dcccbf096c21f6288

Answer (score 0):

After asking and searching around. (useful info: https://www.objc.io/issues/21-camera-and-photos/camera-capture-on-ios/)

This issue is related with the camera exposure, brightness, contrast, white balance factors.

this is what i add to solve the issue

```
//zoom + set exposure for bright senario 
    do {
        try currentDevice.lockForConfiguration()
    } catch {
        // handle error
        return
    }
    currentDevice.videoZoomFactor = 1.0 + CGFloat(1)
    let exposureBias:Float = -0.5
    currentDevice.setExposureTargetBias(exposureBias) { (time:CMTime) -> Void in
    }
    currentDevice.unlockForConfiguration()
```